# React Router Links cause browser crash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So I'm just trying to use `react-router-dom`'s `Link` component and whether it's in my main project or a recreate, it just causes the browser to go blank and throws a console error of `"react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext(...) is null"`.

The homepage is

```
import React from 'react';
import Nav from './Pages/Nav';
import { 
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Pages/Home';
import Gallery from './Pages/Gallery';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Home />
  },
  {
    path: "/Gallery",
    element: <Gallery />
  },
])

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Nav />
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and the link page is

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Nav = () => {
  return (
    <nav>
      <ul style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
        <li style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
          <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
          <Link to='/Gallery'>Gallery</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Nav
```

Commenting out the `Link` components causes everything to work ok again.

Comment: The `Nav` component is outside the `RouterProvider` context.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if my suggestion will solve the issue but for what it's worth here is what you can try:

1 - Remove the space between the name and closing tag of the components like so:

```
element:<Home />
element:<Gallery />
<RouterProvider router={router} />
```

2 - You can remove the div element and wrap everything with BrowserRouter which you can import from "react-router-dom";

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Every component outside the router provider is outside the scope of react-router primitives so it fails because it cant perform the needed actions. You need something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Nav from './Pages/Nav';
import { 
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider
 } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Pages/Home';
import Gallery from './Pages/Gallery';

 const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path:"/",
    element:<Home/>
  },
  {
    path:"/Gallery",
    element:<Gallery/>
  },
  {
    path:"/nav",
    element:<Nav/>

  }
 ])

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <RouterProvider router={router}/>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This way you can go to /nav and Links will work. Anyway, the best way is to add  to the other components not to have a navigation page. So you have to include the nav in every element of your router.

Answer (score 0):

The `Nav` component is outside the `RouterProvider` context, you can fix it by changing the `/` path to a `<Root>` component and rendering the `<Nav>` and an `<Outlet>`, something like this:

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
// import Nav & Home

const Root = () => {

// it is better to use the react-router api:
const path = location.pathname

return <div><Nav/>{path === '/' ? <Home/> : <Outlet/>}</div>
}

export default Root;
```

In `App.js`

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/gallery",
        element: <Gallery />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Nav` component is rendered *outside* the routing context provided by the router component, `RouterProvider` in this case. All components that need to access the provided routing context necessarily need to be rendered under the provider in the ReactTree. In this case you'll need to create a [layout route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes) that renders `Nav` and an [`Outlet`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#outlets) for nested routes to render their content into.

Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { 
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Outlet,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Nav from './Pages/Nav';
import Home from './Pages/Home';
import Gallery from './Pages/Gallery';

const Layout = () => (
  <>
    <Nav />
    <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render element content here
  </>
);

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <Layout />, // <-- Nav now inside context provider
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Home />
      },
      {
        path: "/Gallery",
        element: <Gallery />
      },
    ],
  },
]);

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be using BrowserRouter, Routes and Route like this:

```
import { Navbar, Footer } from 'location';
import { Home, LoginPage } from 'location';

function App() {
return (
<>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/Login' element={<LoginPage />} />
      </Routes>
     <Footer />
  </BrowserRouter>
</>
);
}
export default App;
```